# C# Iterate through a collection of date and time and generate the missing date and time

Tags: c#

I am having some problem in iterating and sampling through a collection of date and time.   What I need is to generate the missing date time by minutes.  The following data is just a small portion, my data contains more then 5000 rows:

```
DateTime[] times = new DateTime[6];
times[0] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 54, 40);
times[1] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 55, 40);
times[2] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 57, 40); // Minute 57
times[3] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 00, 40); // Minute 00 but next hour
times[4] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 01, 40);
times[5] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 12, 40);

for (int i = 0; i < times.Length- 1; i++)
{
    DateTime currentTime = times[i].AddMinutes(1);
    DateTime nextTime = times[i + 1];
    int diff = nextTime.Minute - currentTime.Minute;

    if (diff == 0)
    {
        // Next time is not a missed one.
        Console.WriteLine(times[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(times[i + 1]);
    }
    else 
    { 
        while(currentTime < nextTime)
        {
            // Generate missed date and time.
            currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(1);
            Console.WriteLine(currentTime);
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT:
[image]

WISHED:
[image]

Comment: What do you consider a missing entry, is it just +1 minute? What about seconds, how do you decide what should they be?

Comment: I just need minutes and not seconds.

Comment: Your desired result in unclear. Do you want to get first record and then just strictly increase that time by one minute? Why your desired result has equal seconds in all rows? In other words - can you explain your algorithm?

Comment: I tasked to go thru a collection of DateTime and generate the missing minutes; since I am sampling dateTime by minutes.  I should remove the seconds, if it is confusing I will remove them.  However, I also dislayed the wished result, it should help...

Comment: @doro Still not very clear, but I've found some in your code. You should not check `int diff = nextTime.Minute - currentTime.Minute;` as here you will get in trobles on the hour's border. Instead use `(nextTime - currentTime).TotalMinutes`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev thank you for your time and comments.  Later I will try your suggestion but seems that Magnus found a solution.

Comment: Are the seconds guaranteed to be exactly the same all the time, i.e. is the time difference between items always whole minutes?

Comment: @Guffa as I said, the sampling is by minutes, does not matter the seconds.

Comment: @doro: Yes, but can you rely on the seconds always being exactly the same, as Magnus assumed in his answer?

Comment: Well, for simplicity my sample data containts the same seconds.  However, my actually data does not have the sema seconds.  For me Maguns answer is a step ahead, of course I have eventually consider the seconds.  What would be your advise?  Anyway, I am performing linera interpolation on a set of dateTime and double values.  This might help you.  Thank you.

Comment: @doro: If you check if the time is within a minute interval instead of an exact comparison, it works for any time within the minute. I added some code below.

Comment: Let me try, but I still appreciate your solution. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shave off everything after minutes from the first time to get the start of the minute that it is in. Loop through the minutes and check if there is a time in each minute, and add the minutes that are missing. As it checks if the time is within the minute interval, it works for any second within the minute (and even for fractions of seconds).

```
DateTime[] times = new DateTime[6];
times[0] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 54, 40);
times[1] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 55, 45);
times[2] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 57, 40); // Minute 57
times[3] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 00, 10); // Minute 00 but next hour
times[4] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 01, 34);
times[5] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 12, 16);

DateTime t = times[0];
t = new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, t.Day, t.Hour, t.Minute, 0);
int i = 0;
while (i < times.Length) {
  if (times[i] < t) {
    Console.WriteLine(times[i++]);
  } else {
    if (times[i] < t.AddMinutes(1)) {
      Console.WriteLine(times[i++]);
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
    t = t.AddMinutes(1);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-09-01 11:54:40
2014-09-01 11:55:45
2014-09-01 11:56:00
2014-09-01 11:57:40
2014-09-01 11:58:00
2014-09-01 11:59:00
2014-09-01 12:00:10
2014-09-01 12:01:34
2014-09-01 12:02:00
2014-09-01 12:03:00
2014-09-01 12:04:00
2014-09-01 12:05:00
2014-09-01 12:06:00
2014-09-01 12:07:00
2014-09-01 12:08:00
2014-09-01 12:09:00
2014-09-01 12:10:00
2014-09-01 12:11:00
2014-09-01 12:12:16
```

Comment: Can you suggest me how to move instead of 1 minutes to every 10 minutes?

Comment: @doro: Use `t.Minute / 10 * 10` for minutes when you create the date, then use `t.AddMinutes(10)` instead of `t.AddMinutes(1)` at the two places in the loop.

Comment: I tried but it does not work.  Are you familiar with linear interpolation?

Comment: @doro: I tried it, and it gives the expected result. I have used linear implementation in different context, but I'm not sure how you mean that it would apply here?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime[] times = new DateTime[6];
times[0] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 54, 40);
times[1] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 55, 40);
times[2] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 57, 40); 
times[3] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 00, 40);
times[4] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 01, 40);
times[5] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 12, 12, 40);

var start = times[0];
var end = times[times.Length - 1];

var result = new List<DateTime>(); //The complete range
while (start <= end)
{
    result.Add(start);
    start = start.AddMinutes(1);
}

var missing = result.Except(times); //The missing datetimes
```

Comment: This assumes source list to be sorted.

Comment: @StaWho Yes it does, which it seems to be. And if it is not just add an `Array.Sort(times);` before extracting min and max, or do it with linq.

Comment: I just executed it and it seems to work!  Later I will try with my huge data.  Thank you for you HELP! :-)

Comment: Hi Magnus, I tested your solution with an updated array (times[1] = new DateTime(2014, 09, 1, 11, 54, 50);).  The seconds are not considered.  I know that your solution was based on a set of data which have the same seconds.  What can you suggest me?  Anyway, if it can help you, I am performing linear interpolation on a set of data DateTime and Dounble.

Comment: @doro If the seconds are not to be considered set them all to zero in the input array.

Comment: Well, the input array is just a demo.  The actually data come from a database.  I still appreciate your solution and let you know if I struggle to make them work in my real code.

Comment: @doro Even of the values come from the database you can still truncate time seconds part.

Comment: @Magnus yes you are right.  I can ignore the seconds and still take the last value closest to the next value.  Well, this is how linear interpolation works.  Thank you again and let you know.

Comment: @Magnus I just went into your code, well they work and I think I did a mistake.  In my sample data I said that I didn't care about the seconds, but actally I need them.  Since I am working on implementing linear interpolation I need also to keep any duplication minutes but with different seconds.  For example, 11:54:40 and 11:54:50.  Your way start from the first list items  list[0] and loop thru last items list.Count - 1.  I don't know if you are familiar with the liner interpoation, it need the first and last values between the gap of data missed.